# Why would senator Amidala suspect Count Dooku was behind the bombing?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

At the beginning of Episode II, there's an assassination attempt on senator Amidala's life. Shortly after, a few members of the Jedi council and some politicians have a meeting, with Padme suggesting that Dooku was behind the attack.

Why would she think this? She didn't elaborate at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's some more elaboration in the film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_II_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novelization)). In short, Dooku is a known associate of Nute Gunray, a deeply disreputable character as far as Padmé's people are concerned (he's the guy who arranged the blockade and invasion of their world). On top of that, there seem to be a wide number of assassination attempts going on of people who're known to oppose Dooku's political objectives. She adds up 2 and 2 and gets 4.

> “The separatists have shown themselves not to be above violence,” he explained. “There have been assassination attempts across the Republic.”
>
> **“But wouldn’t Count Dooku and the separatists consider Senator Amidala almost an ally at this time?”** Captain Typho interjected, and both Panaka and Padmé looked at the usually quiet man in surprise.
>
> Padmé’s look quickly turned into a stare; there was an angry edge to
> her fair features. **“I am no friend to any who would dissolve the
> Republic, Captain,”** she insisted, her tone leaving no room for
> debate and of course, there would be no debating that point. In the
> few years she had been a Senator, **Amidala had shown herself to be
> among the most loyal and powerful supporters of the Republic**, a
> legislator determined to improve the system, but to do so within the
> framework of the Republic’s constitution. Senator Amidala fervently
> believed that the real beauty of the governing system was its built-in
> abilities, even demands, for self-improvement.

Note that her fellow senators also instantly suspect Separatists forces.

> Ask Aak, Orn Free Taa, and Darsana, on their floating platforms down
> by the podium, exchanged nervous glances as the cheers and boos echoed
> about the great hall. **The fact that Amidala had just survived an
> assassination attempt and yet was here begging the Senate to put off
> raising an army against the likely perpetrators only added strength to
> her argument,** only elevated Amidala higher in the eyes of many and the
> former Queen of Naboo, having stood firm against the Trade Federation
> a decade before, was already held in high esteem by many. At Ask Aak’s
> nod, Orn Free Taa demanded the floor, and was given it promptly by
> Palpatine.

Comment: Perfect response. Thanks!

Comment: @Charles - The idea behind the Star Wars universe is that you can always dig deeper. The movie contains multiple references to things that were only explained in the books and the books contain references to things you can only understand by reading the various factbooks, etc. It's like a 50+ year-long treasure hunt.

Comment: @Valorum Actually, main idea behind SW books and comics is trying to somehow fill numerous plot holes and lousy script of movies :)

Answer (score 0):

Her Ladyship likely knew that Confederacy of Independent Systems (CIS) leaders, stood to gain from her political demise; mostly in terms of easy tyranny for the CIS. She was not their only target, as the CIS intended the downfall of all democracy; essentially to make slave-labor easier to keep and harder-to-regulate (an advantage from the vantage of CIS slave-owners).

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Confederacy_of_Independent_Systems

CIS leaders (1) Count Dooku, (2) General Grievous (3) eventual The Emperor (Shiev Palpatine, the Sithspawner of the Chancellor)...all stood to gain from the downfall of democracy, via inter-investments: (a) the Trade Federation, (b) the Techno Union, (c) the Retail Caucus, (d) the InterGalactic Banking Clan, (e) the Commerce Guild, and (f) the Corporate Alliance; many of whom attend CIS Board of Directors meetings on Raxulon (The CIS capitol):

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Raxulon

as well as activities on

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Geonosis/Legends

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Utapau/Legends

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mustafar/Legends

The seperatists' OOMs war-robots are sourced from Geonosis.
**Notably, frontal assualts are a waste of troopers, as it's like standing outside an arms-dealer window, strategically.**
... with similar attempts on Hypori:

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hypori

All that anti-societal strata...It seems logical and direct to blame Dooku, as he is a CIS Leader and Separatist Council founder. It's simply a little too simple a guess, as he is not the only leader.